# will creating multiple spring projects that will go into one EAR create multiple spring containers?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, ioc-container

I want to be able to create multiple spring projects in eclipse that will work together that will be created as one EAR. For example, a Spring JMS project, a Spring-WS project, etc. Since these technically can be treated as a sepearte project, will this create multiple spring containers? I would like to have one spring container that will be shared, especially for common configurations such as the data source bean.

Comment: There is no Spring container until you create it. Where you put your jars, wars, or ears has no bearing on this.

Comment: when i create a spring-ws project and run it on weblogic, it is creating a spring-container where my beans will get initialized, is it not?